# Node.js: Return JSON child properties as an array

Tags: json, node.js

This seems like it would be a common question, but I can't find any answers. Given an array of JSON objects, I'd like to access an individual child property, from each object, and return it as a simple array of strings.

Given the following JSON:

```
[
    {
        "FirstName": "Trevor",
        "LastName": "Sullivan"
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "Billy",
        "LastName": "Bob"
    }
]
```

How can I return the `FirstName` property, from each object, as an array of strings?

FWIW, I'm using Node.js 7.2.0 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or using ES6 style:

```
let fNames = jsons.map(obj => obj.FirstName)
```

Where `jsons` is an array of JSON objects

Comment: This is the best of the two, current answers. This is exactly what I was hoping to learn from posting this question. Thank you @sphdev.

Answer (score 1):

```
var names= [];
var arr = JSON.parse(jsondata);
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  names.push(arr[i].FirstName);
}
console.log(names);
```

Where jsondata is your json string
codepen: http://codepen.io/xszaboj/pen/jVZaYp?editors=1011

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. Was hoping for more of a concise answer though, similar to the one posted by @sphdev.